# mysql counts from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join

I've tried to play different mysql joins/selects to get all users who having at least 25 posts or comments.
having

```
users
  id
  valid

posts
  id
  user_id

comments
  id
  user_id
```

There I trying to get all users record with at least 25 comments+posts..

please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
select u.* 
from users u
left outer join posts p on p.user_id = u.id
left outer join comments c on c.user_id = u.id
group by u.id
having (count(p.id) + count(c.id)) >= 25
```